# PHP/MySQL - How to make a calendar where members can sign in for event

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I'm working on a application for our motorcycle club. We have a calendar so anyone can see when and where our events are taking place. Now i want the members to sign in for events so we can easily see who's coming. I already managed to create a record in our database when we create an event. Now the script needs to create a new table, where i can store the subscriptions. So i can make a display to show all subscriptions per event. There's where my knowledge ends...

I guess i need to connect the data from our calendar table to the subscriptions table, but i have no idea how to do that.

Hopefully someone can push me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Krijn

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best and easiest way is to use some ready-to-install widgets, such as Google Calendar, or other of this type. If you have no idea how to do it yourself, that will be the best option for you ;)

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en